# nerdtree textwidth in new windows

Tags: vim, nerdtree, janus

I'm using macvim with the janus plugin that includes nerdtree with it.

The issue that I am having is that whenever I open a file using 'o' from the nerdtree file browser, for some reason it resets the textwidth to 79 in the new buffer that the file is opened into.

I can override this back to 0 in the new buffer and vim will behave correctly, but whenever I switch files, the textwidth gets set back to 79.

I have textwidth set to 0 in my .vimrc file and this is correctly picked up by other files opened in vim, the file browser tab in nerdtree and even the initial empty buffer that is opened when I do 'mvim dir'.  It's just when I use 'o' to open a file that this vim variable gets reset.

Does anyone know how to address this?  I'm seeing the same behavior in gvim with the janus plugin as well.

Comment: Not sure if it comes from NERDTree. Try the following, once the new file is opened (with `tw` set to 79) run `:verb set tw` and post the results. This will help identifying who might be responsible for changing it.

Comment: How are you setting the textwidth in .vimrc? Is it only overridden by NERDTree for certain filetypes or all?

Comment: Could it be that you're opening Python files? Janus forces PEP8 on ft=python https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/janus/vim/core/before/plugin/filetypes.vim#L38

Comment: @Steve- You're correct that this is what is going on. Adding this line to the .vimrc.after fixed it: autocmd FileType python setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 textwidth=0

Comment: Steve McKinney, you should put that as an answer so others can see the question got answered.

Comment: @SteveMcKinney:  Could you please post your comment as an answer, so the question would be answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you're opening Python files?

Janus forces PEP8 on `ft=python` https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/f09d7d383282074ea5477ce7f4f4e2141887a4a7/janus/vim/core/before/plugin/filetypes.vim#L38

Janus should be using `setlocal` instead of `set`